# How do I add an SSL certificate to a CNAME?

Tags: ssl, cname-record

My website has SSL enabled on www.mysite.com and mysite.com, I did it with Let's Encrypt in Apache, but mail.mysite.com is actually a **CNAME** to a different Mail provider. It's basically their website with my domain name. As I can see, it doesn't have an HTTPS. How do I add an SSL certificate to it?

Answer (score 1):

If your mail servers are actually provided by a 3rd party, the correct thing to do is for them to provide SSL certs of their own on their own machines with their host names, and for you to set your MX records in your DNS zone to point to their server(s).  IE,

```
 MX 10 svr42.hostingprovider.com.
 MX 20 svr56.hostingprovider.com.
```

And then let the SMTP protocol worry about getting mail there (that is what MX records are for) and let their folk worry about having a SSL cert.

Now, if that provider DOESN'T have a cert for eSMTP, etc. then.... I'd find a new provider.  Or self host.

Comment: I imagine that the OP was referring to a webmail HTTP website, not a mail server.

Comment: @Steve365 who knows. OP didn't really provide all the gory details needed to know exactly....

Answer (score 0):

You can't. SSL certificates are stored and configured on the web server.

Comment: **It would be pointless,** but the OP could setup a 'proxy' and have the `mail.example.com` terminate on the proxy (with tls setup) and then have the proxy forward requests to the provider.  Traffic would be in the clear between the proxy and the real provider though.

Answer (score 0):

If `mail.mysite.com` points to their server, then *they* have authority (and responsibility) to set up a certificate on that site, not you.

The verification check is, by design, tied to whoever controls the server that the DNS records point to.  So it is by design that if you point mail.mysite.com to some other service, it is they who have the ability to set up a certificate on their server, not you.

Now, if you have control over the DNS records, you could in theory temporarily point them back to a server you control, allowing you to be verified for a certificate on that server.  However, if you set it back to point to someone else's server, then this won't really be useful anymore.  The private key that the certificate refers to resides on the server on which it was generated, and you don't send your private keys to other people, it's bad security practice and it's in their interest to generate their own anyway.